# How can I see the id (and "name") of a CKAN entity (to be used in API update calls)?

Tags: ckan

When looking at the API for updating Packages, Groups, Organizations, or Users, I see that one of the input args is

> id (string) – the name or id of the user to update

(https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.update.package_update). What are the different ways that I can see the "id" of a CKAN user/org/package? The "name"?

Are the IDs just the URL component of the CKAN object that I see when I am, say, updating an Organization? Eg...
[image]

Just from looking at the API docs here (https://docs.ckan.org/en/2.9/api/index.html#ckan.logic.action.update.resource_update) and older examples here (https://docs.ckan.org/en/ckan-1.7.2/api-tutorial.html), the IDs appear to be UUIDs, but I don't know how I would know these values from the CKAN web UI. And is the "name" the name as shown when I, say, view the dataset/Package in the web UI or is it as shown in the URL when looking at the Package (as in the image shown above)?

Could anyone provide more clarity on this? Is this explained somewhere in the docs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what Id/Name you looking, you can query or list them I use rest api like this on `ckan 2.8+`:

```
organizations:
ckan-server:5000/api/action/organization_list

groups:
ckan-server:5000/api/action/group_list

packge: 
ckan-server:5000/api/action/package_search
```

you need to set header with `api_key` (will be deprecated soon).

also some api calls supports name instead of id, so if you willing to update any it will address by name if pressent on request.

the best is first search by name or partial name, then extract id from response.

Comment: So are you saying that the only way to see these things is via the API? A Sysadmin could not find this info on the Web UI? Is there a way to see these things via the backend DB for CKAN (if so where (very new to CKAN))?

Comment: yes, that's correct, not available from ui, but if you use python api, you can see those info too, also through direct queries to postgresql db